# Angular 7 populate site style based on service call

Tags: angular, typescript

Would like to know the best approach to handle

I have a requirement where my site style like color, font are fetched from Config [Service call]

What I have done is in app.component.ts in OnngInt method I am doing a service call and passing the result as an input field to child module.

```
app.component.ts

 brand: Brand;

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.service.getBrandData().subscribe((response) => this.brand = response);


  }

export class Brand {
  brandId: number;
  brandName: string;
  brandCode: string = null;
  brandStyle: BrandStyles;
}

export class BrandStyles {
  brandMainColor: string;
  brandFont: string;
}
```

And in appcomponent.html, I am passing brand info as input field

```
<header [brand]="brand"></header>
```

And in Header.component.html

```
<div [style.backgroundColor]="brand.brandStyle.brandMainColor"
  style="margin-bottom: 30px">
Test site
</div>
```

Issue: I see if there is a delay in getting my brand info via service how do we handle.

Any advice on how to handle these scenarios

Comment: Have spinner in place to show the page is keep loading but does not display until the call returns.

Comment: will try cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would either provide a default `brand` in `app.component.ts`or use a ngIf;else template in the html template;

```
<div *ngIf="brand?.brandStyle;else not_loaded">
    content here ...
</div>

<ng-template #not_loaded>Something to display when brand is not loaded...</ng-template>
```

Comment: good option. @Maihan Nijat said I will try to add spinner and see. I am also going try using async observable. Not sure if it will work..